# How Did They Do That?? Vol. 6: Jetsons Spaceship sound

Tags: sound-design, space, engine

Anyone got any ideas on how they made the  spaceship engine sounds in 'The Jetsons'?

It can be heard here at 13s: http://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_detailpage&v=lhF4gu87rn0#t=13s

I am guessing some kind of really fast resonant filter modulation for that 'wobbly' type sound but really not sure I could recreate it very well myself, it's pretty old so it can't be anything too hi-tech! ... any pointers would be v helpful :)

Comment: I think it may be a sold effect in the Hannah Barbera library if I recall. There's a bunch of Jetsons sounds in there. Just food for thought.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure but have you tried actually analysing it yourself?  Sample it, even off that youtube clip and try pitching it up down by an octave, does it remind you of anything?

At half speed it makes me think of a pair of those squeaky shoes that kids wear, or those dogs toys that squeak - rapidly alternating two different pitches 12121212121212 then pitched up an octave and doppler effect applied

"it's pretty old so it can't be anything too hi-tech"

peoples imaginations are not limited by technology - editing, pitch shifting, reversing & doppler were all easily possible using analog technology (eg a Nagra and a microphone)

if I was yoda I would say something like 'reliance on plugins/hi tech your downfall will be'

Comment: Thanks! I tried the method you mentioned and I know what you mean about the squeaky shoes, I will try some experiments! Regarding my 'not high tech' comment, I didn't mean that it was in any way inferior, just that it would probably be some kind of charming solution such as pitched up squeaky shoes :) Having said that, Yoda definitely does have a point...